# Retrieving Specific MySQL Field Data in PHP Based on Primary Key Value using $_GET['ID']

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to find the correct way of pulling specific field data from a MySQL database.
I am using the `$_GET` but it shows all the data and id. How can I get the data from a specific ID(primary keys).

```
        echo "<td>" .$view['Absence_Code']."</td>";
        
        echo "<td>" .$view['Details']."</td>";
        
        echo "</tr>";
```

2nd File

```
<body>

<?php
        
    

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM userapproval WHERE ID=$ID";

    $data = mysql_query($sql);
    
?>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ). **You are also wide open to [SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)**

Comment: Your query is hardcoded and doesn't use any $_GET parameters, so it doesn't matter WHAT you pass in to the script - you'll always be running the SAME query.

Comment: Basically: `$id = (int)$_GET['id']; $sql = "SELECT * FROM userapproval WHERE Approval = 0 AND ID = $id";` but it's not recommended because it's not safe. Take a look at @JohnConde comment.

Answer (score 1):

Add `report.php?ID=`

```
 echo "<td>" .'<a href="report.php?ID='.$view['ID'].'">'.$view['ID'].'</a>'."</td>";
```

Comment: Thank you user876345! it really helps! forgot to put 'ID'. A lot of thanks too, John Conde, Marc B and Ofir Baruch!! Now I can smile.. hehe